# Vagrant Symfony caching permissions issue

Tags: symfony, vagrant

This issue has come up a lot, but haven't found the solutions yet.

I've setup vagrant with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) and seems to be running fine. However my Symfony application is complaining about saving cache.

```
Failed to save key "xxx".
touch(): Utime failed: Operation not permitted
```

All that I could find is that it has something todo with the permissions. But I don't understand what is going wrong.

The synced_folder has:

```
owner: www-data
group: www-data
```

And apache:

```
user: www-data
group: www-data
```

The folder has write permissions, even setting `777` doesn't solve the problem. I also deleted the `var/log` directory so the web application creates it. It does create the folder, but cache still can't be written. I don't know how to fix this issue with this setup.

**EDIT**
I tried `sshfs` as sync_type which solves the problem. But makes the vagrant setup slow.

Below my full vagrant file.

PuPHPet config.yaml file:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: bento/ubuntu-16.04
                box_url: 'false'
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    machine1:
                        id: php72
                        hostname: php72.puphpet
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.103
                            forwarded_port:
                                port1:
                                    host: '9201'
                                    guest: '22'
                        memory: '512'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path:
                    - puphpet/puppet/modules
                    - puphpet/puppet/manifests
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /opt/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            folder1:
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
                source: /Volumes/codedisk
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: nfs
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - bash-completion
        - htop
        - vim
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: nl_NL.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
            - nl_NL.UTF-8
        timezone: Europe/Amsterdam
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
resolv:
    install: '1'
    nameservers:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
    domainname: ''
    searchpath: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: present
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        vhost1:
            server_name: awesome.test
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.test
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '0'
            locations:
                php_html:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome
                    location: /
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    index_files:
                        - index.html
                        - index.php
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                php_php:
                    www_root: /var/www/awesome
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    autoindex: 'off'
                    internal: 'false'
                    index_files:
                        - index.php
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        vhost_zjo:
            servername: project.test
            docroot: /var/www/project.test/public
            port: '80'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_key: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_chain: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_certs_dir: LETSENCRYPT
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                sf4_fm_DEF:
                    provider: filesmatch
                    path: \.php$
                    sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                    setenv:
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                sf4_dir_DEF:
                    provider: directory
                    path: /var/www/project.test/public
                    directoryindex: index.php
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    rewrites:
                        rewrite_1:
                            rewrite_base: ''
                            comment: ''
                            rewrite_cond:
                                - '%{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$'
                            rewrite_rule:
                                - '^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]'
                        rewrite_2:
                            rewrite_base: ''
                            comment: ''
                            rewrite_cond:
                                - '%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$'
                            rewrite_rule:
                                - '^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]'
                        rewrite_3:
                            rewrite_base: ''
                            comment: ''
                            rewrite_cond:
                                - '%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f'
                            rewrite_rule:
                                - '.? - [L]'
                        rewrite_4:
                            rewrite_base: ''
                            comment: ''
                            rewrite_rule:
                                - '.? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]'
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: ''
        webserver_service: ''
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '7.2'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - xml
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        pool1:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 8.0.5
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        ruby1:
            default: '1'
            bundler: '1'
            version: '2.4'
            gems:
                - deep_merge@1.2.1
                - activesupport@5.1.4
                - vine@0.4
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '6'
    npm_packages: {  }
mariadb:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    users:
        user1:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        database1:
            name: dbname
            collate: utf8_general_ci
            sql: ''
    grants:
        grant1:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    users:
        user1:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        database1:
            name: dbname
            collate: utf8_general_ci
            sql: ''
    grants:
        grant1:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.6'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases:
        database1:
            dbname: dbname
            owner: dbuser
    users:
        user1:
            username: dbuser
            password: '123'
            superuser: '1'
    grants:
        grant1:
            role: dbuser
            db: dbname
            privilege:
                - ALL
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 3.6.2
    databases:
        database1:
            name: dbname
            user: dbuser
            password: '123'
redis:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    databases:
        database1:
            name: dbname
            owner: www-data
            group: www-data
            sql_file: ''
mailhog:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users:
        user1:
            admin: '1'
            name: admin
            password: '123'
            tags:
                - admin
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 6.1.2
        java_install: true
    instances:
        instance1:
            name: es-01
            jvm_options:
                - '-Xms2G'
                - '-Xmx2G'
```

Comment: awesome.test or project.test ?

Comment: @Buze, yeah, just for local development ;)

Comment: Yes, but which one is not working?

Comment: @Buze, project.test

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56701622).

Run this:

```
$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd
```

And set Vagrantfile like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "nfs"
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)